# Row Level Locking in Mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, rowlocking

I have 5 rows in a table (1 to 5). I want row 2 lock for some update and in the meanwhile if someone tries to update row 4, then he should able to update.

I am trying this with code below, but I feel its placing lock on table level rather than row level.

------ session 1

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE t=1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE test SET NAME='irfandd' WHERE t=2;
COMMIT;
```

----- session 2 (which is being blocked)

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE test SET NAME='irfandd' WHERE t=4;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What is your storage engine?

Comment: i am using innodb + using with out primary key constraint

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `FOR UPDATE` use `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. `FOR UPDATE` prevents other transactions to read the row as well. `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` allows read, but prevents updating.

Reference: [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

------ session 1

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE t=1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
UPDATE test SET NAME='irfandd' WHERE t=2;
COMMIT;
```

----- session 2 (which is not being blocked anymore :) )

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE test SET NAME='irfandd' WHERE t=4;
COMMIT;
```

**Update:**

Realizing that **the table has no index** on `t`, I have the following explanation:

First, transaction T1 locks the *row 1* in `SELECT * FROM test WHERE t=1 FOR UPDATE`

Next, transaction T2 tries to execute `UPDATE test SET NAME='irfandd' WHERE t=4`. To find out which row(s) are affected, it needs to scan all rows, including *row 1*. But that is locked, so T2 must wait until T1 finishes. 
If there is any kind of index, the `WHERE t=4` can use the index to decide if *row 1* contains `t=4` or not, so no need to wait.

**Option 1:** add an index on `test.t` so your update can use it.

**Option 2:** use `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, which is intended for putting a read lock only.
Unfortunately this option creates a deadlock. Interestingly, T2 transaction executes (updating row 4), and T1 fails (updating row 2). It seems that T1 read-locks *row 4* also, and since T2 modifies it, T1 fails because of the transaction isolation level ([REPEATABLE READ by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read)). The final solution would be playing with [Transaction Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-model.html), using `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `READ COMMITTED` transaction levels.

The simplest is **Option 1**, IMHO, but it's up to your possibilities.

Comment: not meeting my requirement. I want particular row lock neither the whole table locking.

Comment: It seems that if you have any kind of index on `t` (primary, unique or general), there are no locks on the table, using either `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. If you have no index, the lock appears. It has some relation the index. Updating the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I found below option is more appropriate i generate 40000 numbers from concurrent session on the same time. I didnt found any duplicate number. Without below command i generate 10000 numbers and found 5 duplicate numbers.

START TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM test WHERE t=1 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE test SET NAME='irfandd' WHERE t=2;

COMMIT;